# "No less than" vs. "None less than"

Tags: meaning, differences, idioms, synonyms, idiom-meaning

Is the expression **none less than** similar to the idiom **no less than**?
Which form is preferable to use in the following example:

> None less than the country's president attended today's meeting.
>   OR
>   No less than the country's president attended today's meeting.

Please mention why if they are similar, and in which resource is  the idiom "none less than" is mentioned!

Answer (score 2):

I think this really boils down to a question of when you use *no* and when *none*.

*There will be no less than sixty people at the gathering*.

*Few people in Britain drink Bovril these days, none less than me*

**Editing later:**

The usage to which you further refer is highly idiomatic, and it is perhaps worth considering for a moment what it is saying. It doesn't mean that nobody of any significance less than the President was there. It means that one of the people there *was no one less than the President*.

Personally I would prefer to say *no less than...* but as *none* is short for *no one*I don't think it really matters.

Comment: Which one is correct?
"None less than the country's president attended today's meeting." or "No less than the country's president attended today's meeting."

Comment: @omareg94 See my further editing to the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Neither. Say "none other than".

It accomplishes litotes (Wow! It was the president himself!) without inviting the misunderstandings of "no/none less than" which had to be explained twice in this thread.